# Is it possible to not push / present previewed controller on iOS

Tags: ios, preview

I've created a controller to previewed using `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate`.

What I need is the previewed controller should only be previewable; without getting pushed or presented eventually. So far, I cannot find a way to handle this requirement. Any ideas? Thank you.

Edit: Yes, if I somehow do not force touch, it does not call `func previewingContext(UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit: UIViewController)`. But I need to disable it completely.

Comment: `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate` is deprecated. You should be using `UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate` instead.

Comment: 'UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer

Comment: Even if I use `UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate`, does it provide the feature I need?

Answer (score 0):

For earlier than iOS 13 I have no solution yet. But for iOS 13 and later, as @bsod mentioned above comment `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate` is deprecated and when we use its successor `UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate` we have a solution.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: {
        let contr = AController.init()
        return contr
     })
     // do not implement `actionProvider`
  }
```